# JQuery/Javascript: Error Message not displayed on Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, error-handling

So basically I have a form where a user is allowed to create a group. An error message is supposed to be displayed if the user does something they are not supposed to for example they enter a group name that already exists. My code is shown below.

Any help would be appreciated.

Just a side note, any error message that is related to the field works fine. For example, if you don't enter anything into a required field, error message is displayed as it should on the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with that code that's creating the group form, but it seems that

```
%div{:id => "id___all__"}
```

may not be creating the field

```
$('#non_field_errors');
```

that you're trying to reference in

```
jQuery.each(errors, function(i, error) {
    if (field != '__all__') {
        $fieldId = $('#id_'+field);
    } else {
        $fieldId = $('#non_field_errors');
    }

    $fieldId.closest('.control-group').addClass('error');
    $fieldId.parent().append(
        $('<span class="error_span">').addClass('help-inline').append(error));
    })
```

Basically, it SEEMS to me, without being 100% familiar with all this, that you're trying to place the errors into

```
$('#non_field_errors');
```

when you should be putting it into

```
$('#id___all__');
```

So nothing's happening. Let me know if this points you in the right direction. The loop itself appears to be working fine.